# Составить условие if

Tags: условия, php, if

Всем привет.

Никак не могу понять как правильно составить условие.

Есть некий блок, который нужно выводить на различных страницах.
Есть ряд настроек.

$inCat = может иметь значение true, false. Выводить только в категориях или нет

$inNews = может иметь значение true, false. Выводить в просмотре новости или нет

$catId = id категории

$newsId = id новости

Сейчас у меня так

```
if (
    ($inCat == true && $catId != '0') OR // если показываем в категориях и если есть категория
    ($inCat == false) // если показываем везде
)
{ echo 'Мой блок'; }
```

Нужно добавить сюда условие $inNews. Если true, то выводим блок еще и в новости. При этом проверяя $newsId, на пустоту.

Что-то никак не могу правильно сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (
  ($inCat and $catId > 0)
  or
  ($inNews and $newsId > 0)
  or
  (!$inCat and !$inNews)
) { 
  // показываем
}
```

Мое мнение - лучше ввести еще настройку `$showAnywhere`, код будет логичнее

```
if (
  $showAnywhere
  or
  ($inCat and $catId > 0)
  or
  ($inNews and $newsId > 0)
) { 
  // показываем
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все получилось. Добавил так же $showAnywhere.